# remove animation completed event from an element in WPF code?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-animation

As shown below, I have a group of elements which I animate separately with two DoubleAnimations targeting opacity. I then listen to the animation completed events so that they cycle until I interrupt the cycle individually.

```cs
for(UIElement myElement in ListOfElements)
{
    DoubleAnimation fadeIn = new DoubleAnimation(0, 1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(fadeInSeconds));
    DoubleAnimation fadeOut = new DoubleAnimation(1, 0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(fadeOutSeconds));
    fadeIn.Completed += (s, e) => 
        myElement.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, fadeOut);
    fadeOut.Completed += (s, e) => 
        myElement.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, fadeIn);
}
```

In some cases, I want to stop the cycle of animation for a specific element by removing the animation AND the listener for the `fadeout.completed` event. Stopping it with `myElement.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, null)` works fine but it does not prevent the Completed event from firing at the time it would have completed. That is, stopping the animation does not prevent the .Completed event from firing. So to remove the Completed listener, I think must retrieve the "fadeout" animation for a specific element and then unsubscribe the listener with `-=`

First, how can I find the active animations for a given element, so that I can access it's Completed event.

Second, how to remove the listeners from that animation's completed event?

Comment: Why are you doing it so complicated, instead of fading in and out repeatedly with a single DoubleAnimation or a Storyboard?

Comment: Hi Clemens, thanks for taking time to ask. It is an unusual use case. 

My reason for doing this is because I have many objects that I am fading in and out at different cycles, rates and number of repetitions, each determined at runtime when each completes a fade in or a fade out. In other words, I may or may not fade in an object that has just faded out. This is decided per object at runtime when the fade animation completes. [I am manipulating this effect as part of an art project] 

So assuming I do have a good reason for doing this ;) - does anyone have suggestions? Much appreciated!